# Is it possible to convert output of PHP print_r($xmlChild) back to XML string?

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file loaded into PHP via simpleXML(). The following is the output of print_r($childNode). Is it possible to allow user to edit this in a textarea and then save it back into the XML format? If so, what sort of validation should I use when the text area content is submitted? Thanks!

```
$childNode = $xmlString->Child;
print_r($childNode);
```

Output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [ID] => Surveys
    [Contact] => Hou Fang Zhao
    [Email] => email@gmail.com
    [Img] => pic.png
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure u can create XML from string, but you should use DOMDocument Class.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

$element = $dom->createElement('test', 'This is the root element!');

 // We insert the new element as root (child of the document)
 $dom->appendChild($element);

 echo $dom->saveXML();
```

output:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <test>This is the root element!</test>
```

now u need prepare data as string from textarea submited from form and put into DOMDoceument Class